# Effecientcy of using multiple subselects

Tags: subquery

I'm trying to gather multiple related pieces of data for a master account and create a view (e.g. overdue balance, account balance, debt recovery status, interest hold). Will this approach be effecient? Database platforms are Informix, Oracle and Sql Server. Doing some statistics on Informix I'm just getting 1 sequential scan of auubmast. I assume the sub-selects are quite effecient because they filter down to the account number immediately. I may need many sub-selects before I'm finished. On top of the question of efficiency are there any other 'tidy' approaches?

Thank you.

select
    auubmast.acc_num,
    auubmast.cls_cde,
    auubmast.acc_typ,

```
(select
sum(auubtrnh.trn_bal)
from auubtrnh, aualtrcd
where aualtrcd.trn_cde = auubtrnh.trn_cde
and auubtrnh.acc_num = auubmast.acc_num
and (auubtrnh.due_dte < current or aualtrcd.trn_typ = 'I')    
) as ovd_bal,

(select
sum(auubytdb.ytd_bal)
from auubytdb, auubsvgr
where auubytdb.acc_num = auubmast.acc_num
and auubsvgr.svc_grp = auubmast.svc_grp 
and auubytdb.bil_yer = auubsvgr.bil_yer
) as acc_bal,

(select
max(cur_stu)
from audemast
where mdu_acc = auubmast.acc_num
and mdu_ref = 'UB'
) as drc_stu,

(select
hol_typ
from aualhold
where mdu_acc = auubmast.acc_num
and mdu_ref = 'UB'
and pro_num = 2601
and (hol_til is null or hol_til > current)
) as int_hld
```

from auubmast

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, the answer to this is that correlated subqueries should be avoided whenever possible.

Using them will result in a full table scan for your view, which is bad. The only times you want to use subqueries like this is if you can limit the range of the main select to only a few rows, or if there really is no other choice.

When you're running into situations like this, you might want to consider adding columns and precalculating them on an update trigger, rather than using subqueries. This will save your database a thrashing.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Clayton.Not sure why this was voted down indicating that there was no research- I researched and ran explain on various different styles. I also tried to find other similar questions. Some were suggesting these types of subquries act like joins and are indexed anyway - is that correct?

Comment: In addition - Overdue balances are really 'real-time' things so triggers would not help in that case. Overdue really needs to derive from the balances on transactions past their due date. I can use left outer joins to get this sort of info but some of these approaches might also require unions to build the necessary values.